# Workflow Task Escalation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, visual-studio-2013

I need to create a workflow which creates a task, then assign it to the manager1 of the user. If manager1 does not accept within 2 days, need it to escalate to the manager2. If manager2 does not accept it in 3 days, it should be escalated to manager3.

I do not like to use timer jobs as it does not exactly take 2/3 days, no Pause until as it will keep workflow holding till the number of days are gone, no looping as it consumes more resources.

What are the options I have?

Comment: I'm confused. You need to create a workflow in SharePoint and you don't want to use SharePoint workflow. Have you looked at other workflow engines?

Comment: No I mean this process is not generally addressed with SharePoint.

Comment: Approval workflows are a standard process in SharePoint. You've described a custom workflow above. If you're not happy with the options in SharePoint for custom workflows, how can this forum help? Maybe you can re-word your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about the Pause Until action in SharePoint Designer as described in a SharePoint Workflow to send Email on a specific Date and Time, perhaps you might want to look at it's Visual Studio Counterpart [DelayUntil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowservices.activities.delayuntil(v=office.15).aspx).

If DelayUntil is too easy, or not enough of a difference from Pause Until, I suggest reading up on Stages in SharePoint 2013 Workflow in Visual Studio. Andrew Connell has a great write up of [how things have changed in 2013](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/SP2013Whats-new-with-Workflow) to allow better scale and performance without putting a burden on your main SharePoint Farm.

In addition, there's a very complex state machine Visual Studio example on MSDN samples from the same author, [SharePoint 2013: Route workflows to states depending on actions and events](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Route-25a25d87). The example includes a delay.

For more on approval workflows in SharePoint, I recommend checking out the [MSDN Code Samples for SharePoint](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=workflow&f%5B1%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B1%5D.Value=SharePoint%20Server%202013). There are some great workflow examples from experienced SharePoint developers like Andrew Connell. And a few cover workflow.

Comment: Wait for field change waits for the list item to change. I cannot change the list item. I will be relying on task list.

Comment: You're right. Updated to DelayUntil and added scalability and Stage information.

Comment: You can wait for item event in another list.

Comment: It seems this is the only answer. Will see.

Answer (score 0):

Your process event based on time, if you use a date variable and set to it the Task created date plus the time you want (2 days, 3 days....) and make it as a due date for the managers task based in your process.
I think it'll work correctly